# React : Test button click navigation with react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I got this little piece of code with a button that navigate to another page :

```
export const Index = () => {
    return (
        <Box>
            <h1>Some title</h1>
            <Button component={Link} to={'/creation'}>Créer</Button>
        </Box>
    )
}
```

I would like to test that when I click on that button I actually navigate to my new page but I can't make the test work :

```
it("Should navigate to page 2 on button click", async() => {
        render(<Index />, {wrapper: BrowserRouter})
        const user = userEvent.setup()

        expect(screen.getByText(/Créer/i)).toBeInTheDocument() // => this works

        await user.click(screen.getByText(/Créer/i))
        expect(screen.getByText(/Page 2/i)).toBeInTheDocument() // => doesn't work
    })
```

For information : It works when I actually deploy my App

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Index does not contain any Routes.
Actually it's contained inside Routes in the App.tsx like that :

```
class Main extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <ThemeProvider theme={MuiTheme}>
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <AppRoutes/>
                </BrowserRouter>
            </ThemeProvider>
        );
    }
}
```

AppRoutes.tsx being :

```
const AppRoutes = () => {
    return (
        <Routes>
            <Route index element={<Index/>} />
            <Route path={"/creation"} element={<CreationIndex/>} />
        </Routes>
    )
}
```

In order to make the code works for test all I had to do was :

```
it("Should navigate to page 2 on button click", async() => {
        render(<AppRoutes/>, {wrapper: BrowserRouter}); // => AppRoutes instead of Index
        const user = userEvent.setup()

        expect(screen.getByText(/Créer/i)).toBeInTheDocument() 

        await user.click(screen.getByText(/Créer/i))
        expect(screen.getByText(/Page 2/i)).toBeInTheDocument() 
})
```